# CMIS Alfresco Copy all versions of a document

Tags: java, alfresco, cmis

Basic copy CMIS method copy only the first version of document.

How to copy all versions because iterate versions for copy one by one throws duplicate document exception

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Comment: Find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying a document via CMIS behaves exactly the same as copying a document in Alfresco Share. The "current" version of the object is used as the source of the copy. None of the versions will be copied.

If you want to do a copy that maintains the version history, you'll have to get all the versions of the source object, then copy the first version to create the new object, then check in each subsequent version, in order, on the copied object.

For objects with a deep version history this could be a very expensive operation, so think hard about whether or not it makes sense to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you trying to do, but I think you don't have to copy every separate version by itself. I think the document and it's versioning are copied when you copy the document.

Nevertheless this is how you get all document versions:

```
Document document = ...;
document.getAllVersions();
```

Comment: The problem is : document.copy(targetFolder); only copy the most recent version and this version become initial version for the new document.

Comment: What repository are you using?

As I recall copy basically creates a new Document, therefore it has nothing to to do with the document it was copied from.

Does move perhaps fit your needs? I don't see a good reason to duplicate documents across DMS.

There is another option also - multi-filing, but support for it depends on your repository. Basically it allows you to have the same document in multiple folders (or better to say to have more parents).

https://chemistry.apache.org/java/0.10.0/maven/apidocs/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/inmemory/storedobj/api/MultiFiling.html